# UIView animateWithDuration returns immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I'm trying to animate a label embedded in a UIView.

this is the code :

```
-(void)displayText:(NSString*)text {


[label setText:text];


[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [labelView setAlpha:1.0];
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.8
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [labelView setAlpha:0.0];
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
}
```

To verify, the method is called, i set a breakpoint.

The calls return immediatly but only the end of animations is displayed.

I wired the UIView to the controller.

Pls help, I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance !
Patrick

Answer (score 5):

Correct,

When you animate views like this the animation doesn't actually happen on screen until the next pass of the runloop (i.e. once your method returns).

UIView will coalesce animations that are programmed sequentially.

Use the completion block to fade back out. The code looks a bit odd but it works great!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [labelView setAlpha:1.0];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:5.8
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                      animations:^{[labelView setAlpha:0.0];}
                                      completion:nil];
                 }];
```

In response to your comments:

The animations won't start until the next run of the runloop. They won't start until your app finishes what its doing. If you wait in the loop you will have the same problem and also freeze up your interface. Consider using individual labels for each letter, and add a progressively bigger delay for each animation. All these animation instructions will be queued up at once and then played out over the course of the next however many seconds. Imagine you are like a movie director, you tell each actor what to do in the next scene. Then, once everyone knows what to do you sit back and yell "action" and watch it all play out.

Comment: hey jack ! Thx for your answer .. But didn't work, just tried it out ;( The animateWithDuration.. method returns again immediatly.

Comment: yes. They will return immediately. You are basically giving instructions to UIView to do something at a later point. your calls will complete and when your method returns then the animations will get to work. If you wanted something else to happen please update your question.

Comment: ok, maybe I'm getting this totally wrong... What I'm doing : In a loop, I'm calling this method for a sequence of characters. I want to fade-out/in each character one after another. Maybe, do i have to wait in the loop, before calling -(void)displayText:(NSString*)text next time ?

Comment: Example : I'm calling the method like :

Comment: for (int i=0; i < [words length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [words characterAtIndex:i];
        [self displayText:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
    }

Comment: ok, but what confuses me : I increase the delay for each iteration of the loop (in 10 seconds steps) but still, I immediatly get presented the last animation...

Comment: btw, in this case, i animated a single label

Comment: each iteration of the loop you change the same label. The changes and animations won't happen on screen until all iterations of the loop finish. Use a new label for each thing you want to show in this loop.

Comment: yes, yes i understand. But i simply don't get, why i cant do chained animations on the same thing. Even switching between alpha 0.0 and 1.0 in 6 chained blocks doesn't work ;(

Comment: ok jack, maybe I lack fundamental understanding of animations. First, I will read apple documentation before wasting your time. Thanks anyways

Comment: @jackslash This is extremely helpful.  How did you know that UIView coalesces the animations that are programmed sequentially?  Is this described somewhere in Apple docs?  Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html should beef up your understanding