# IOS block pointer copy issue.

Tags: ios, pointers, block

See the following animation execution block, how does the UI control pointer clickButton copy from stack to heap? By reference (retain) or just copy pointer value (not deep copy)?

Thanks in advance.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 animations:^(void){
    clickButton.alpha = 1.0;  // clickButton is class variable. 
}];
```

Comment: Copying is copying. It's not retaining. You can't really copy the 'value' of a block - because it's essentially the actual code it executes. In reality, blocks are Objective-C objects containing a function pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3: It's very awkwardly said, but he's actually asking about the memory semantics of the captured variable, not of the block itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a block is copied (which it is in this case), any objective-c objects that are referenced by the block are retained (and then released when the block is dealloc'd).

In this case, if `clickButton` was a local variable outside the block, it would be retained inside the block. However, you said it was a "class variable", which I assume you mean it's an instance variable. Because of that, the block actually retains `self`, since the reference to the ivar is really an implicit lookup of the ivar within `self`.

In MRR (non-ARC) code, any obj-c objects which are marked with the `__block` storage qualifier are actually not retained by the capturing block. This is for technical reasons, but it has been taken advantage of by many people. However, in ARC code, `__block`-qualified variables do get retained (and released) by the block. If you need a non-retained object under ARC, you can use `__unsafe_unretained` instead. However, in ARC code, weak references typically solve the same problem that `__unsafe_unretained` variables do, but much more safely.

---

Since the block here has a temporary lifetime (it only lives for the duration of the animation), there's no problem with retaining self. However, for more permanent blocks whose lifetime are actually tied to that of `self` (e.g. they're stored in an ivar, or on an object that `self` owns), you should be careful not to introduce a retain cycle. If you're using ARC, weak references can help you here.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Yes, your illustration is very clear, plus one question, when the above animation will be executed by system runloop?

Comment: @jianhua: This animation API you're calling will execute the animation immediately, hold on to the block temporarily until the animation is done, and then invoke and release the block

Comment: Really? I set the animation time as 10s, but my debugging shows that the calling returns back very quickly, so I suspect that the animation will be added into system runloop then executed later.

Comment: @jianhua: The animation does not block. That would be terrible. Animations are inherently asynchronous, which is why they have a completion block. So the animation will be started immediately, and will run in the background until it's done, at which point it will invoke the completion block on the main thread again.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see, plus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963184/uiview-animatewithduration-returns-immediatly.