# Is it posible to do multiple animations on UIView without using completion block

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

This is simple question just for illustrating point, my concrete code is much more complicated.

Let say that I have UILabel that is position on TOP LEFT.
With this code, I will move it to TOP RIGHT:

```
    // labelMove is moved to TOP RIGHT
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 40.0f);
     }
                     completion:nil];
```

If I have this code:

```
// labelMove is moved to TOP RIGHT
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:2.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
     labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 40.0f);
 }
                 completion:nil];

// labelMove is moved to BOTTOM RIGHT
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:2.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
     labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 450.0f);
 }
                 completion:nil];
```

It will not start from TOP LEFT, but from TOP RIGHT, and then go BOTTOM RIGHT.
Somehow first animation is not animated, only the last one.
I do not get it why, but that is not so important.
I can put second in completion: block in first and then it will work.
Like this code.

```
// labelMove is moved to TOP RIGHT
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:2.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
     labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 40.0f);
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // labelMove is moved to BOTTOM RIGHT
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                           delay:2.0f
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                      animations:^
                      {
                          labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 450.0f);
                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                 }];
```

**QUESTION**
Is it posible to have effect from last code but without using completion block in any way.
That is very important for me.
I try with CABasicAnimation, but could not do it, maybe somebody with more experience can ?
I am sure that there must be some way, but I just can not figure it out.

Comment: LOL! Hahahahaha! You shouldn't created duplicate questions you know. You could use key frames to do an animation from top left to top right to bottom right in one animation. But that is ONE animation. i.e. you don't get to do any logic in between each movement. It will go all the way or none of the way. However, just use completion. It's not gonna give you a disease and can be done well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call multiple animation, one after another one same UIView object, without using completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260252/call-multiple-animation-one-after-another-one-same-uiview-object-without-using)

Comment: The only other way to do this (which is really not a good idea) is to delay the start of the subsequent animations. But you have no guarantee of getting the timing right. Also you have to call all the animations in one place.

Comment: @Fogmeister bout questions address same problem. I started second question because it is not dependent on my project, so it is easier to understand the problem. Regarding your answers for first question I could do it with delegates (at least I think so), but I will try to avoid it. Currently I am learning Core Animation details to se is this even possible. Thanks on your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with no completion block does not work because you are attempting to animate the label to two different locations at exactly the same point in time.  This is physically impossible.

When you run that second animation inside a completion block, you are running it *after* the first animation, instead of *at the same time*.  To achieve the same effect, dispatch the second animation so that it is performed after the first animation.  Since the first animation will take 2.0 delay + 1.0 duration = 3.0 seconds to complete, dispatch after 3.0 seconds.  See below.

```
// labelMove is moved to TOP RIGHT
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:2.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^
 {
     labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 40.0f);
 }
                 completion:nil];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // labelMove is moved to BOTTOM RIGHT
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:2.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         labelMove.center = CGPointMake(250.0f, 450.0f);
     }
                     completion:nil];
});
```

Just be aware that without using the completion block, you cannot insure the first animation is truly finished animating.  In practice this should usually be fine.

Comment: Thanks on your replay, but I still have a problem. I have tried your code in iOS simulator (from 6.0 to 7.1) on Xcode 5.1.1. And it it still starting from TOP RIGHT (where should it be after first animation), not from TOP LEFT (where is label set in StoryBoard). On what setting did yuo manage to do both animations one after the other ?

Comment: Sorry about that, my original code was wrong and has been edited.  Instead of adding to the delay you should dispatch the animation code after the time it takes the first animation to complete.  The reason is because the animation blocks get run immediately.  If you NSLog() the center, you will see it is the new point immediately after -animateWithDuration:... is run.  The display gets updated as an animation, but the first animation is cancelled after the second is run, so this is why it moves immediately (i.e., looks like it is starting from the TOP RIGHT).

Comment: This is working, I can even add one more with another dispatch_after. Whole point is to use dispatch_after and put correct time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CAKeyframeAnimation, and create a path using the two points.

Here are some examples from apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/PropertyAnimations.html

Comment: good to know. What I need is to have to independent animations, and then to call them in one method.